# Owl Carousel doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented the code and files as explained on the owl carousel website but what appears are only large images at full width, and the slider doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Edited: After i implemented it into my website, it doesn't work again, Please check the update of the JavaScript i added below: Note there are two sliders on my website

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mine.js"></script>
        <title>UltraMax</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

                var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
                  [{b:900,d:2000,x:-379,e:{x:7}}],
                  [{b:900,d:2000,x:-379,e:{x:7}}],
                  [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1,sX:2,sY:2},{b:0,d:900,x:-171,y:-341,o:1,sX:-2,sY:-2,e:{x:3,y:3,sX:3,sY:3}},{b:900,d:1600,x:-283,o:-1,e:{x:16}}]
                ];

                var jssor_1_options = {
                  $AutoPlay: 1,
                  $SlideDuration: 800,
                  $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,
                  $CaptionSliderOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
                    $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
                  },
                  $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
                  },
                  $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
                  }
                };

                var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

                /*responsive code begin*/
                /*remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing*/
                function ScaleSlider() {
                    var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                    if (refSize) {
                        refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1920);
                        jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                    }
                }
                ScaleSlider();
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
                /*Jssor Slider Begin end*/
            };

                    $(document).ready(function() {

                  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

                      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

                      items : 4,
                      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
                      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

                  });

                });
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="owl-demo">      
          <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
        </div>    

        </body>
        </head>
        </html>
```

Here is the css

```
#owl-demo .item{
  margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Always load dependent plugin after jQuery

Comment: @satpal what do you mean?

Comment: Change the sequence of `<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` load `jquery.min.js` before `owl.carousel.js`

Comment: weew it works :D i didnt know this is the mistake

Comment: okay im sorry, well it happens again when i implemented it to my website

Same Issue Happens again

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mine.js"></script>

Comment: @SamMohamed Are there any errors in your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: Yes there is

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (UltraMax.html:65)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @paulRoub i added the new code, Please check the edit

Comment: You're including jQuery twice, once as a local jquery.min.js and once from ajax.googleapis.com. Pick one, and make sure it's included before owl.carousel.js.

Comment: alright, it works now, Thanks @PaulRoub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sequence of jquery libraries like this:-

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

And you are good to go.